# Determining the text around a field in microsoft word using visual basic macro

Tags: vba, ms-word

So the goal of my macro is to take a word document that is ordered like this:

```
<image>
<caption>
<image>
<caption>
```

and to scrape the document and create a NEW document that looks like this:

My current code looks like this:

```
Sub tryinterleave2()
'
' tryinterleave2 Macro
'
'
Dim oField As Field
Dim oCurrentDoc As Document
Dim oNewDoc As Document
Dim sFileName As String
Dim sFigName As String
Dim ParaNum As Integer

Set oCurrentDoc = ActiveDocument
Set oNewDoc = Application.Documents.Add

For Each oField In oCurrentDoc.Fields

If oField.Type = wdFieldIncludePicture Then
    sFileName = Replace(oField.Code, "INCLUDEPICTURE", "")
    sFileName = Replace(sFileName, "MERGEFORMAT", "")
    sFileName = Replace(sFileName, "\*", "")
    sFileName = Replace(sFileName, "\d", "")
    sFileName = Replace(sFileName, Chr(34), "")
    sFileName = Replace(sFileName, "\\", "\")
    sFileName = Trim(sFileName)
    oNewDoc.Range.InsertAfter sFileName & vbCrLf


ElseIf oField.Type = wdFieldSequence Then
    sFigName = oField.Result
    oNewDoc.Range.InsertAfter sFigName & vbCrLf
End If

Next oField

oNewDoc.Activate
Set oField = Nothing
Set oCurrentDoc = Nothing
Set oNewDoc = Nothing

End Sub
```

I am getting the image location fine....but i can only get the RESULT of the caption sequence field. So instead of getting "Figure 1: Spring" I am getting "1". I have literally JUST started messing with VBA today so the answer could be straightforward. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I am guessing there should be screenshots in between the first few lines. If so, they are missing.

Comment: I am trying to solve this, but the `oNewDoc.Range.InsertAfter` leaves me clueless. I do not understand what you are trying to do here...

Comment: @BernardSaucier: I assume he is trying to create a list of picture file names and the related captions.

Comment: Can't check now but something like sFigName =oField.Result.Paragraphs(1).Text may do what you need. Also, replacing " \d" rather than just "\d" may avoid problems with any pathnames containing \dsomething

Comment: Still have not figured out a solution, but you may on your own with this simple tip : place a `MsgBox sFileName` or `MsgBox sFigName` before & after each manipulation. For example : `MsgBox sFigName`  `sFigName = oField.Result`  `MsgBox sFigName`

Comment: I actually figured this out. Sorry about the incomplete question...I dont know what happened. However, I set up a for loop that looped through each paragraph and inside it i set up another for loop that checked for any fields within that paragraph. Inside that I put in if / else that determined the kind of field and exported to the new word document appropriately. With this method I was always aware of the paragraph I was on and therefore didnt have to rely on any association between the field object and the rest of the document (which i dont believe there is)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually figured this out. Sorry about the incomplete question...I dont know what happened. However, I set up a for loop that looped through each paragraph and inside it i set up another for loop that checked for any fields within that paragraph. Inside that I put in if / else that determined the kind of field and exported to the new word document appropriately. With this method I was always aware of the paragraph I was on and therefore didnt have to rely on any association between the field object and the rest of the document (which i dont believe there is)